# I got this message (CANNOT_GROUP_WITHOUT_AGG) from a simple query

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-query-language

I how to fix this error message?

`Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: 
CANNOT_GROUP_WITHOUT_AGG`

I got that error message just from a simple query formula, I already tried to search about it and try with the curly bracket `{ ... }` but it doesn't fixed,
Can anyone help me or ever experienced it?

```
=QUERY(ANSWER!C:C, "SELECT * GROUP BY C", 0)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't have an agreggation function (such as `sum`, `avg`, `count` in `SELECT`), there is no use for `GROUP BY` - you may just delete it.
If you wish to present unique records, use `distinct` instead.

Comment: I already add a count function
`=QUERY(ANSWER!A:C, "SELECT A, B, C, COUNT(C) GROUP BY C", 0)`
but why it's still give an error?  `Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: ADD_COL_TO_GROUP_BY_OR_AGG: A`

Comment: Because everything in select should be either aggregation function or in group by as well. And by the way - there is no logic in grouping by c and counting c at the same time.

Comment: So how to showing a list of email that unique? but showing I got a bunch of mails in column C, so that's why I use group by to sort it, is there any alternative way? by the way, in column A is a date of email. and Column B is a website of the email, so 1 email can be there multiple times with different date and websites.

Comment: There is no distinct in the Google Query language, AFAICT.